# Live Mesh beta on Windows 7 - Did anybody get it working?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-live-mesh

I have Live Mesh beta installed on 64 bit Windows 7 but cannot connect to the computer remotely. The "Manage devices" page gives this information:

```
This device is synchronizing but cannot be remotely accessed. Check the Live Mesh notifier on the device to see if Live Mesh remote desktop enhancements need to be installed.
```

However, I cannot find instructions on how to use the "notifier" to "see" if Live Mesh remote desktop enhancements are installed or how I could install them.

When I originally installed (both times) Mesh I did tell it to install "remote desktop enhancements". Does this just not work with Windows 7 and/or 64 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got Live Mesh Beta working on some computers. But Live Mesh 2011 works.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine of windows 64bit. I have it working on a number of machines, a mixture of 64 and 32bit.

Just checking that you installed Live mesh from [here](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh?os=other)

Heres a link to instructions to check the notifier, particularly if you have renamed a device at a[link text](http://help.live.com/help.aspx?project=wl_core&market=en-us&querytype=topic&query=wl_core_proc_optimizeremoteaccess.htm)ll.

If still have difficulties, say, and i'll investigate further.
Jp